# How do we fetch the ResultSet in the desired format when the fields to be fetched are coming as part of the request in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with around 20 columns. At any point in time I don't want to fetch all the columns but only the selected columns and I don't know what could those columns be since it's coming from the request as a parameter. What's the right way to achieve this ?

I have tried implementing  this using the native queries but having a hard time parsing the result set to the desired response format.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT name, model, desc FROM Product");
query.getResultList();
```

Now this result set is so generic that I am not able to convert it to the required product model by passing Product.class as a parameter to the query as it fetches only the 3 fields and the rest are missing. And I can't have a predefined projection as it's coming from the API request as a parameter.

Comment: You would need to roll your own solution as Spring Data has no support for dynamic field fetching. The Hibernate docs note that  column optimisations are rarely worthwhile so you would be as well fetching all the data and rolling your own solution to only serialize the required fields in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've done it. Apparently you can get the ResultSet as a list of Tuple. I just had to iterate over this list and make a Map for each entry in result set so I can map it using ModelMapper. Here tags are a list of columns to be read.

```
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(preparedQuery,Tuple.class);
    List<Tuple> resultList = query.getResultList();
    List<Product> resultDto = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Tuple tuple : resultList) {
        HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        for (String tag : tags) {
            data.put(tag, tuple.get(tag));
        }
        resultDto.add(mapper.map(data, Product.class));
    }
    return resultDto;
```

Thanks for all who responded to this.

Answer (score 0):

The response you get will be in this format 
**Map< String,Object >**.
Create a ProductDTO class and convert this map into ProductDTO with the
help of ModelMapper.

```
ProductDTO productDto = new ModelMapper().map(resultMap, ProductDTO.class);
```

Comment: Result that I get is List<Object[]> not Map< String,Object>. I'd be ok to convert it as DTO if it's Map< String,Object >

Comment: If it is Object what is the class type.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want other fields means just add the @JsonInclude annotation at top of the entity class.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Product{
```

Edit:
 Create the Constructor in Product Class

```
public Product(String name,String model,String desc){
   this.name=name;
   this.model=model;
   this.desc=desc;
}

 String query = String.format("select new pakageName.Product(e.name, e.model,e.desc) from Product as e);
 Query queryObject = (Query) em.createQuery(query);    
 List<Product> result = queryObject.getResultList();
```

Native query only returns the Object. So try this like the below mentioned one.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. Problem here is not that. I'm stuck with the conversion part itself.